# How to present multiple categories options in a single django model field

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to set up a Django model, and I want a particular field called categories, to contain a list of options that will be rendered to the front-end as a list of options that the user can choose from.

I am new to Django and python, and I really don't have an idea of how to solve this problem.

```
from django.conf import settings

from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Bio                     = models.TextField(blank=False)
    personalWebsiteURL      = models.URLField(blank=True)
    personalWebsiteName     = models.URLField(blank=True)

    categories = **model needed here**


    def __str__(self):
        return self.details or ""
```

I want the options for the categories to come from the backend or model, which is a long list of categories. And I want the categories list or options to be saved as a model field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a long list and that's gonna change quite frequently, you're better off creating a category model and use a ForeignKey for that.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    slug = models.SlugField(...)

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If the list of category is a fixed (or not so often updated), you can use `choices` for that.

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    CATEGORIES = (
        (1, 'Category one'),
        (2, 'Category two'),
        (3, 'Category three'),
        ...
    )
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES)
```

Comment: is there a way to use both foreign key and the choice at the same time? and is choice still a good option if I plan on adding more categories over time?

Comment: As far as I know there’s not way to use FK and choices for the same field and if you keep in adding categories you can still use choices but you’ll need to change the code every time you do that.

Comment: To understand better, I want to be the one to add to the categories later in the future to the backend, not the users. the users are simply selecting from the categories made available to them. so going by what you said, Foreign Key would be perfect for that?

Comment: FK would be better and easy to add categories due to the fact you (as an admin) could go to the Django admin and add categories. However, choices would work too if you (as a developer) will be the only one adding categories, but in this case, you'd need to open your codebase and add them manually. So, I'd say go with FK.